# How to create and render a React Component after babelify/transpiling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jinja2, babeljs, browserify

I have a hello world react component that is written in JSX, transpiled with babel, and then included in the hello.html template of a Flask app. What I have working is creating and rendering the component before transpiling as such:

```
const hello = <Hello  name="world" />;
ReactDOM.render(hello, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

How can I do those two steps in a `<script>` tag in my hello.html template? My goal is to be able to pass that name variable from the template to the component and then render it.

A little more context:

The JSX hello.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>Hello {this.props.name}!!!</div>
    )
  }
}

//The following works:                                           
//const hello = <Hello  name="world" />;
//ReactDOM.render(hello, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

hello.html looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>ASDF</div>
    <div id="hello"></div>
  </body>                           
  {# The following line is a post babelify (transpiled) hello.js #}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/hello.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {#
      What goes here? The code in the above section does not work.
      The transpiled code defines a "var Hello = /*#__PURE__*/ function (_React$Component) { ...".
      const hello = Hello(); does not throw an error, but also does not render or pass an argument.
      hello.render(); is also something that I have tried, along with arguments for div/id to render in and name.
    #}
  </script>
</html>
```

Correction: Calling `Hello()` does not throw an error if the script is `text/babel`, in which case the script probably isn't doing anything.

The Flask route looks like this:

```
@app.route(u'/')
def index():
  return render_template(u'hello.html', name="universe")
```

Comment: `hello.render` function will not work because that is the function react uses to determine your output in the Hello class. This is totally different from `ReactDOM.render`. ReactDOM is the one that manipulates the browser dom and makes your `Hello` component `render` output show on the browser. Have you tried using **SystemJS or Webpack**?

Comment: I decided to go with Browserify instead of Webpack (not familiar with SystemJS). At this step wouldn't I be running into the same problem? I'd have ES* code that I somehow need to pass variables to and render?

Comment: You need to import `react` and `react-dom` using browserify then and also create a script and add `ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'))` to it. So you are still following your normal react procedures. Just that babel handles the transpiling and what goes on behind the scene for you.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I believe I've done that in the `hello.js` above. The problem is that if I `ReactDOM.render()` there I can't pass in props because I don't know what their values will be.

Comment: Are the props not coming from the server then? You should read up on [react server rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html).

Comment: The props come from a Jinja2 template rendered by Flask server side.

Comment: I just edited the answer, I haven't worked with Flask or Jinja2 before. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can pass variables from your server application to react component:

1. Use the html `data-variable` prop.
2. Create a global variable. Something like `window.variable`

Then you should be able to access variable as a props like `props.variable` in your react-component.

My recommended approach I would take is to use a bundler such as SystemJS (version 2), and you will have something like the following:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="node_modules/core-js-bundle/minified.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script type="systemjs-importmap" src="systemjs.imports.json"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/extras/named-exports.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('../.playground/index.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>ASDF</div>
        <div id="hello"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And `index.js` will look something like this

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    (< Hello/>),
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then your systemjs-importmap will look like this

```
{
  "imports": {
    "react": "../node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js",
    "react-dom": "../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
    // ... other named exports you want to add like the Hello component here
  }
}
```